# Context menu hover highlight permanently visible on desktop

Tags: windows-7

I've been having a weird issue for a couple of days, which happens whenever I click an entry in a context menu.

The first weird thing is that when I open a context menu, it will not have full opacity, like shown here:

[image]

Once I hover over the context menu, it will be fully opaque.

[image]

When I then click an entry, the highlight of that entry will be permanently visible on top of all other windows on my desktop.

[image]

The only way to get rid of this highlight is to restart the Desktop Window Manager. What causes this and how can I fix it?

One interesting aspect to this is, this only happens when I open the menu by using the mouse. When I press the menu button on my keyboard, the menu will appear right away and the highlight won't persist .